# how to parse a file

Tags: java, parsing

Alright, i have an assignment and i dont know how to parse the file. Is string tokenizer my best option?
The file has commas, newlines and spaces. S is the starting state and small a is the input and the big A is the next state. Should i parse the file into seperate variables and run it through a switch case to simulate a state machine?

This is the file

```
‘Ends in a
2
S, a, A
S, b, S
A, a, A
A, b, S
F: A
aba
bbaabba
bbabab
aaaab
b
a
```

Thank you so much because i just cant seem to get started...

Comment: If you're looking for any real code whatsoever in an answer, you need to choose **a single** language tag. Java or C++, which is it?

Comment: Your question is vague. The title and first sentence suggest you don't know how to parse the file, but then you end up asking how to implement a state machine based on this data. Perhaps you'd rather split this into separate questions to make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

> My biggest question is how can i parse the file?

Like any other text file.  There are literally millions of examples on how to do this on the web.

I would look for examples using the `Scanner` class.

> I am not very good at parsing files. Especially in this situation.

With practice it will get easier.  Doing this assignment will help.

> Should i use dilimeters?

The file has delimiters so I don't why you wouldn't.

> comma and newline?

Your file has commas, newlines and spaces.

> and put the states into an array and the inputs ( a,b) into a second array?

Java is an object orientated programming language. Perhaps using Collections like Map and Objects is a better choice.

> Should i check for digits, isaplha?

I would just assume the file is formatter correctly and read numbers when you expect to have a number and strings when you expect to have a word/token.

> lower case and uppercase alpha?

Not sure if this is a consideration.

> i am thinking i need a switch and a couple of cases to handle the state transitions?

If your states were handled in Java code, I would say yes. However you states are being read from a text files and stored in a data structure. In this case its simpler not to use switches.

> Can someone explain how i should go about handling this file so i can process it?

Read it, store the data in a structure, process the inputs.

> I am also confused on how to handle the :F A in that file..

This is information you need to record to determine when your DFA stops.

Comment: This still doesn't help me. This is pretty much what i thought originally. How can i handle starting state, input symbol, next state? Do they go into one array?

Comment: You can parse them with a Scanner, store them in a class of your making (one fields for state, one for input, one for next state). As I said, I wouldn't use an array.

Answer (score 1):

Java is an object-oriented language so build a series of classes that reflect the real world.

Example:

What do you have? And what do they need to be able to do

- DFA

  - has a series of states
  - needs to be able to accept/reject input strings
- State

  - has a collection of inputs to look for and states to transition to based on input
  - needs to be able to check for a token and transition to a new state

So these kind govern how you should lay out your classes (members and methods).  So you should make a DFA class and it should have a method: public boolean process(String input).